# Layout changes if device setting is force RTL

Tags: android

How to override Android option RTL(Force RTL layout direction) to keep an app LTR. I have Tried to set an option in `manifest.xml` but it did not work

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:supportsRtl="false"
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

Comment: from where you are changing the layout direction. from devs options?

Comment: yes from developer option and i wanna to override it in my app

Comment: well, developers options are not a part of user-options. you cant override them. actually they can override your code.

Comment: but there are devices i have seen. in which there is option for users to switch rtl-ltr. in those cases the code works very well

Comment: so here is not any workaround??

Comment: i think so. there is no way you can fight against devs options